# Zoysia Grass Overrunning Groundcover

Tags: grass, ground-cover

I have a well-established area of Confederate Jasmine groundcover that is beginning to be overrun by Zoysia grass growing under the concrete curb border. Is there any way to kill the Zoysia without injuring the Jasmine. Hand weeding is almost impossible due to the density of the Jasmine.

Comment: Hi CFB, could you post a picture to illustrate what you're telling us?